# Como desativar spring security

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Boa noite, estou aprendendo jsf, então acompanhei uns videos do Leandro Costa no youtube, achei bem didático e etc. No final do curso ele disponibiliza o código fonte, porém como o projeto usa spring security no login e ele não passou o script sql toda página que tento acessar dá o erro HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied. 
Já tentei criar o banco manualmente, porém sem sucesso. Então cheguei a conclusão que é melhor tirar a autenticação pra poder usar a aplicação.

spring-security.xml

```
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.faces" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/restrict/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="permitAll"/>

    <form-login login-page="/login.faces" authentication-failure-url="/login.faces?erro=true"
                default-target-url="/restrict/home.faces"/>     
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/acessonegado.faces" />
</http>                

<!-- NO PROJETO SEMERU PADRÃO FIZEMOS DESSA FORMA -->  
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="sha"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                           users-by-username-query="SELECT Login, Senha, 'true' as enable FROM pessoa WHERE Login=?"
                           authorities-by-username-query="SELECT Login as username, Permissao as authority  FROM pessoa WHERE Login=?"/>               
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<b:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <b:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/semeru_jsf_maven_db" />
    <b:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <b:property name="username" value="root" />
    <b:property name="password" value="admin" />
</b:bean>
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>semeru_jsf_maven</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <!--        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>-->
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Duração da sessão -->

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>  

<!-- Configurações do tema do PrimeFaces -->
<context-param>  
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
    <param-value>sam</param-value>  
</context-param>         

<!-- Filtros do Spring  -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

    <!-- Configurações do JavaServer Faces -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Bloqueia o browser de acessar arquivos xhtml</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>xhtml files</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>

<!-- Configurações do PrimeFaces -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comentei os trechos que ativam o spring security do seu web.xml tentando explicar o que cada trecho é responsável por fazer, é importante salientar, que embora o spring security vá ficar desativado com este web.xml, a aplicação pode estar utilizando este contexto em vários lugares e não funcionar corretamente.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>semeru_jsf_maven</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <!--        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>-->
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Duração da sessão -->

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<!-- Este parâmetro refere-se ao contexto do Spring
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>  -->

<!-- Configurações do tema do PrimeFaces -->
<context-param>  
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
    <param-value>sam</param-value>  
</context-param>         

<!-- Estes filtros são responsáveis por interceptar qualquer request e direcioná-lo para o Spring
Filtros do Spring  
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
-->

    <!-- Configurações do JavaServer Faces -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Aqui como explicado abaixo, é responsável por blqouear acesso ao xhtml caso o usuário não esteja autenticado
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Bloqueia o browser de acessar arquivos xhtml</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>xhtml files</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>
-->

<!-- Configurações do PrimeFaces -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou Ricardo, muito obrigado por me ajudar.

Comment: De nada cara, caso tenha alguma dúvida, não exite em perguntar.